# Can't detect Asus Xtion

Tags: usb, roslaunch, openni

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I followed the tutorial from [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/70585/roslaunch-openni_launch-opennilaunch-no-devices-connected/) as I had the same problem and it still does not work.

My lsusb still have that output :

```
ros@ros-K56CM:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 008: ID 22b8:7090 Motorola PCS 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 003 Device 011: ID 1d27:0601  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13d3:5165 IMC Networks
```

I install the driver for V1.5 and I'm using the openni_camera package rollback usb.

Still I have that error when I try `roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch`

```
 Warning: USB events thread - failed to set priority. This might cause loss of data...
 terminate called after throwing an instance of 'openni_wrapper::OpenNIException'
 what():  unsigned int openni_wrapper::OpenNIDriver::updateDeviceList() @ /home/ros/catkin_ws/src/openni_camera/src/openni_driver.cpp @ 125 : enumerating image nodes failed. Reason: One or more of the following nodes could not be enumerated:

Image: PrimeSense/SensorV2/5.1.2.1: USB transfer timeout!

[FATAL] [1395670174.772256226]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1395670174.772255542]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1395670174.772256770]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1395670174.772728833]: Service call failed!
```

Any help is appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/143721/can%27t-detect-asus-xtion/) by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1172 on 2014-03-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solve by using openni2_camera and openni2_launcher from source...

Go [there](https://github.com/ros-drivers/openni2_launch/tree/groovy-devel) and [there](https://github.com/ros-drivers/openni2_camera/tree/groovy-devel), enter  `git checkout groovy` in both folders and use `catkin_make`. Then it should be working.

---

Originally posted by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) with karma: 1172 on 2014-03-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1